# elasticbeanstalk checking the config file output

Tags: python, django, amazon-web-services, config, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

Many thanks in advance for your insight and guidance. I finally managed to set my python-django project up with amazon's elasticbeanstalk. All works except the collectstatic command doesn't seem to be running since I get 404 on all my static stuff. 
I have been checking logs and sshing to find out what is wrong but not luck yet ... this is my config file:

```
container_commands:
 00_echo:
  command: "echo Baaaaaaa!!!!"
 01_collectstatic:
  command: "source /opt/python/run/venv/bin/activate && python myapp/manage.py collectstatic --noinput"

option_settings:
 "aws:elasticbeanstalk:application:environment":
  DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE: "myapp.settings"
   "PYTHONPATH": "/opt/python/current/app/vitagina:$PYTHONPATH"
 "aws:elasticbeanstalk:container:python":
  WSGIPath: myapp/myapp/wsgi.py
  NumProcesses: 1
  NumThreads: 18
 "aws:elasticbeanstalk:container:python:staticfiles":
  "/static/": "www/static/"
```

Should I be able to see the "Baaaaa!" in the logs somewhere? How do I check to make sure my commands are actually running?

Many thanks

Comment: no luck seeing my Baaa echo! but i realized one major problem i had, I didn't put my config file in .ebextension folder. Hope this helps someone... not to self, read the friendly manual!

Answer (score 0):

You can look for logs inside /var/log/eb-commandprocessor.log and /var/log/eb-activity.log to see what commands were executed and what the result was.